# Filemaker XSL using if statements

Tags: xslt, filemaker

I'm trying to build an xml file from data in a Filemaker database. I can get the basic structure of the XML to work but am having issues rendering portal rows in the right way.

Here is the end result of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
<product>
<model>Model</model>
<caliber>Caliber</caliber>
<submodel>Sub Model</submodel>
    <Dimensions>
        <label>Overall length</label>
        <label>Overall height</label>
        <value>178 mm</value>       
        <value>138 mm</value>
    </Dimensions>

    <weight>
        <label>Overall weight</label>
        <label>with magazine</label>
        <value>739 g</value>
        <value>91 g</value> 
    </weight>
</product>
```

The Model and Caliber and Submodel items are fields in a table in my database. The dimensions and weight are pulling from a related table as a portal. The relationship key is the model.

Each portal row as a Category, Label and Value.

I'm trying to write an if statement in the XSL file that will grab all the portal rows with a category of "Dimensions" and group them together. The same for Weight.

Here is my current working XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fmp="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="fmp">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <product>
            <xsl:for-each select="fmp:FMPXMLRESULT/fmp:RESULTSET/fmp:ROW">
                <model>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[2]/fmp:DATA"/>
                </model>

                <caliber>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[1]/fmp:DATA"/>
                </caliber>

                <submodel>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[4]/fmp:DATA"/>
                </submodel>

                <specs>
                    <xsl:for-each select="fmp:COL[10]/fmp:DATA">
                        <category>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </category>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:for-each select="fmp:COL[8]/fmp:DATA">
                        <label>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </label>
                    </xsl:for-each>

                    <xsl:for-each select="fmp:COL[9]/fmp:DATA">
                        <value> 
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </value>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </specs>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </product>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will output all the information I need but puts all the categories from the portal row together. I'm very new to XSL and don't know how to formulate the if statement.

I need to change the info inside  to the if statement.
Here's what I was playing with:

```
<xsl:if test="fmp:COL[10]/fmp:DATA= 'Dimensions'">
    <Dimensions>
        <label>Overall length</label>
        <label>Overall height</label>
        <value>178 mm</value>       
        <value>138 mm</value>
    </Dimensions>
</xsl:if>
```

Here is the raw export from Filemaker.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
   <ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
   <PRODUCT BUILD="03-15-2012" NAME="FileMaker" VERSION="ProAdvanced 12.0v1" />
   <DATABASE DATEFORMAT="M/d/yyyy" LAYOUT="" NAME="HK Product Database.fmp12" RECORDS="61" TIMEFORMAT="h:mm:ss a" />
   <METADATA>
      <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Caliber" TYPE="TEXT" />
      <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Model" TYPE="TEXT" />
      <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="ModelID" TYPE="TEXT" />
      <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="PrimaryCategory" TYPE="TEXT" />
      <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="ProductID" TYPE="TEXT" />
      <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="SubModel" TYPE="TEXT" />
      <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Models::WP Post ID" TYPE="NUMBER" />
      <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Specs::SpecLabel" TYPE="TEXT" />
      <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Specs::SpecData" TYPE="TEXT" />
      <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Specs::SpecCategory" TYPE="TEXT" />
   </METADATA>
   <RESULTSET FOUND="61">
      <ROW MODID="1" RECORDID="196">
         <COL>
            <DATA>9 mm x 19</DATA>
         </COL>
         <COL>
            <DATA>P59</DATA>
         </COL>
         <COL>
            <DATA>P59</DATA>
         </COL>
         <COL>
            <DATA>Semi-Automatic Pistols</DATA>
         </COL>
         <COL>
            <DATA>P30-9</DATA>
         </COL>
         <COL>
            <DATA>P30</DATA>
         </COL>
         <COL>
            <DATA>181</DATA>
         </COL>
         <COL>
            <DATA>Overall length</DATA>
            <DATA>Overall height</DATA>
            <DATA>Overall width w/lever</DATA>
            <DATA>Barrel length</DATA>
            <DATA>Sight radius</DATA>
            <DATA>With magazine</DATA>
            <DATA>Magazine</DATA>
            <DATA>Magazine capacity</DATA>
            <DATA>Trigger system</DATA>
            <DATA>Trigger pull (N)</DATA>
            <DATA>Trigger travel</DATA>
            <DATA>Sights</DATA>
         </COL>
         <COL>
            <DATA>178 mm</DATA>
            <DATA>138 mm</DATA>
            <DATA>35 mm</DATA>
            <DATA>98 mm</DATA>
            <DATA>149 mm</DATA>
            <DATA>739 g</DATA>
            <DATA>91 g</DATA>
            <DATA>15 Cartridges</DATA>
            <DATA>SA/DA</DATA>
            <DATA>* 20 + 4/-2 (SA) 
51 +/- 5 (DA)</DATA>
            <DATA>.25 inch (SA)
&lt; .55 inch (DA)</DATA>
            <DATA>Fixed (Open square notch rear sight with contrast points)</DATA>
         </COL>
         <COL>
            <DATA>Dimensions</DATA>
            <DATA>Dimensions</DATA>
            <DATA>Dimensions</DATA>
            <DATA>Dimensions</DATA>
            <DATA>Dimensions</DATA>
            <DATA>Weight</DATA>
            <DATA>Weight</DATA>
            <DATA>Other Specifications</DATA>
            <DATA>Other Specifications</DATA>
            <DATA>Other Specifications</DATA>
            <DATA>Other Specifications</DATA>
            <DATA>Other Specifications</DATA>
         </COL>
      </ROW>
  </RESULTSET>
</FMPXMLRESULT>
```

It's not working right. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit:

Here is an update of where I"m at:
This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fmp="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="fmp">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <product>
            <xsl:for-each select="fmp:FMPXMLRESULT/fmp:RESULTSET/fmp:ROW">
                <model>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[2]/fmp:DATA"/>
                </model>
                <productID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[5]/fmp:DATA"/>
                </productID>                
                <caliber>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[1]/fmp:DATA"/>
                </caliber>

                <submodel>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[4]/fmp:DATA"/>
                </submodel>

                <xsl:if test="fmp:COL[10]/fmp:DATA= 'Dimensions'">
                    <Dimensions>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </Dimensions>
                </xsl:if>

                <specs>
                    <xsl:for-each select="fmp:COL[10]/fmp:DATA">
                        <category>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </category>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:for-each select="fmp:COL[8]/fmp:DATA">
                        <label>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </label>
                    </xsl:for-each>

                    <xsl:for-each select="fmp:COL[9]/fmp:DATA">
                        <value> 
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </value>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </specs>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </product>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Renders this XML:

```
<product>
<model>P30</model>
<productID>P30-9</productID>
<caliber>9 mm x 19</caliber>
<submodel>Semi-Automatic Pistols</submodel>
<Dimensions>9 mm x 19P30P30Semi-Automatic PistolsP30-9P30181Overall lengthOverall heightOverall width w/leverBarrel lengthSight radiusWith magazineMagazineMagazine capacityTrigger systemTrigger pull (N)Trigger travelSights178 mm138 mm35 mm98 mm149 mm739 g91 g15 CartridgesSA/DA* 20 + 4/-2 (SA) 
51 +/- 5 (DA).25 inch (SA)
&lt; .55 inch (DA)Fixed (Open square notch rear sight with contrast points)
DimensionsDimensionsDimensionsDimensionsDimensionsWeightWeightOther SpecificationsOther SpecificationsOther SpecificationsOther SpecificationsOther Specifications</Dimensions>
<specs>
<category>Dimensions</category>
<category>Dimensions</category>
<category>Dimensions</category>
<category>Dimensions</category>
<category>Dimensions</category>
<category>Weight</category>
<category>Weight</category>
<category>Other Specifications</category>
<category>Other Specifications</category>
<category>Other Specifications</category>
<category>Other Specifications</category>
<category>Other Specifications</category>
<label>Overall length</label>
<label>Overall height</label>
<label>Overall width w/lever</label>
<label>Barrel length</label>
<label>Sight radius</label>
<label>With magazine</label>
<label>Magazine</label>
<label>Magazine capacity</label>
<label>Trigger system</label>
<label>Trigger pull (N)</label>
<label>Trigger travel</label>
<label>Sights</label>
<value>178 mm</value>
<value>138 mm</value>
<value>35 mm</value>
<value>98 mm</value>
<value>149 mm</value>
<value>739 g</value>
<value>91 g</value>
<value>15 Cartridges</value>
<value>SA/DA</value>
<value>* 20 + 4/-2 (SA) 
51 +/- 5 (DA)</value>
<value>.25 inch (SA)
&lt; .55 inch (DA)</value>
<value>Fixed (Open square notch rear sight with contrast points)
</value>
</specs>
</product>
```

Using the same source XML. The dimensions if statement is working but now just need to separate that content.

Comment: What’s not working about it? Can you show us the source XML?

Comment: We need to see the raw XML export. Just export the same data without applying any stylesheet and add the resulting XML to your question.

Comment: Added in the raw export from Filemaker. @buck, there is no source XML. All data was imported from various .csv files. I'm just trying to structure the export in the format I need.

Comment: What you posted is what I meant by “source XML”. In an XSL transformation, there’s the source, stylesheet, and result.

Comment: @Buck, sorry for the confusion. Still new to all of this.

Comment: I just tried the given XML and the stylesheet with your added `xsl:if` and the result document had the `Dimensions` you wanted. Am I misunderstanding what you want? Can you share the output you’re getting versus what you expect? (No problem re confusion, happens to the best of us!)

Comment: @BuckDoyle, Funny! In my prepping of code for this post, I must have fixed something I did wrong! The <Dimensions> content is coming out but is showing all the elements instead of just the dimensions.  The last part of the XML shows the separation of items.Thanks for your help by the way!

Comment: Wow, this XML is hard to work with. I’m thinking about it…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s my suggested stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fmp="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="fmp">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="fmp:FMPXMLRESULT/fmp:RESULTSET/fmp:ROW">
        <product id="{fmp:COL[5]/fmp:DATA}">
                <model>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[2]/fmp:DATA"/>
                </model>
                <caliber>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[1]/fmp:DATA"/>
                </caliber>

                <submodel>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[4]/fmp:DATA"/>
                </submodel>

                <dimensions>
                    <xsl:for-each select="fmp:COL[10]/fmp:DATA[text()='Dimensions']">
                      <xsl:variable name="category-position" select="count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1"/>

                      <xsl:variable name="label" select="ancestor::fmp:ROW/fmp:COL[8]/fmp:DATA[$category-position]"/>

                      <xsl:if test="$label = 'Overall length' or $label = 'Overall height'">
                        <value label="{$label}"><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::fmp:ROW/fmp:COL[9]/fmp:DATA[$category-position]"/></value>
                      </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </dimensions>

                <weight>
                    <xsl:for-each select="fmp:COL[10]/fmp:DATA[text()='Weight']">
                      <xsl:variable name="category-position" select="count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1"/>
                      <value label="{ancestor::fmp:ROW/fmp:COL[8]/fmp:DATA[$category-position]}"><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::fmp:ROW/fmp:COL[9]/fmp:DATA[$category-position]"/></value>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </weight>
              </product>
          </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<product id="P30-9">
  <model>P59</model>
  <caliber>9 mm x 19</caliber>
  <submodel>Semi-Automatic Pistols</submodel>
  <dimensions>
    <value label="Overall length">178 mm</value>
    <value label="Overall height">138 mm</value>
  </dimensions>
  <weight>
    <value label="With magazine">739 g</value>
    <value label="Magazine">91 g</value>
  </weight>
</product>
```

I notice you only wanted two dimensions values in your output, so I added a filter based on the `label`.

**NOTE**: what follows applies to an earlier version of the stylesheet. I changed it to create a result more like what I describe below.

Is your output XML already specified? Because I think it could be improved to be more XML-y:

```
<dimensions>
  <dimension label="Overall length">178 mm</dimension>
  <dimension label="Overall height">139 mm</dimension>
</dimensions>
```

Or really, if you know in advance what your key/value pairs are:

```
<dimensions length="178mm" height="139mm"/>
```

If you have control over the design of your output XML, might as well take advantage of its features rather than emulating the awkward Filemaker output. `<label/>` and `<value/>` pairs that are connected by nothing other than position are pretty un-XML, better to combine them into an element!

Comment: The `xsl:if` is redundant here, isn't it? Note also that you cannot do the same thing for Weight, as shown in the requested output.

Comment: The `if` is useful if you want to keep out an empty `Dimensions` element. It depends on what XML comes out of Filemaker for different records. But if you know there’ll always be dimensions, sure, you can remove it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean re weight: the source document doesn’t have an `Overall weight` key…?

Comment: Oops, I see what you mean now about weight, @michael.hor257k. Fixing…

Comment: @BuckDoyle, thanks so much for your help. I do like the suggestion about more XML-y. What's the best way to get that label in the style sheet based on data from the database? I left a comment above.

Comment: I updated the stylesheet to create what I consider more idiomatic XML. Key changes: ID as attribute on `product`, all lowercase element names. I also moved `<product></product>` inside the `for-each` row because I think that’s correct?

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work for you?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:fmp="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult" 
exclude-result-prefixes="fmp">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <product>
        <xsl:for-each select="fmp:FMPXMLRESULT/fmp:RESULTSET/fmp:ROW">
            <model>
                <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[2]/fmp:DATA"/>
            </model>
            <caliber>
                <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[1]/fmp:DATA"/>
            </caliber>
            <submodel>
                <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[4]/fmp:DATA"/>
            </submodel>
            <Dimensions>
                <xsl:for-each select="fmp:COL[10]/fmp:DATA[.='Dimensions']">
                    <xsl:variable name="i" select="count(preceding-sibling::fmp:DATA) + 1" />
                    <label><xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[8]/fmp:DATA[$i]"/></label>
                    <value><xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[9]/fmp:DATA[$i]"/></value>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Dimensions>
            <Weight>
                <xsl:for-each select="fmp:COL[10]/fmp:DATA[.='Weight']">
                    <xsl:variable name="i" select="count(preceding-sibling::fmp:DATA) + 1" />
                    <label><xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[8]/fmp:DATA[$i]"/></label>
                    <value><xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[9]/fmp:DATA[$i]"/></value>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Weight>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </product>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Given your input, the following result is obtained:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<product>
   <model>P59</model>
   <caliber>9 mm x 19</caliber>
   <submodel>Semi-Automatic Pistols</submodel>
   <Dimensions>
      <label>Overall length</label>
      <value>178 mm</value>
      <label>Overall height</label>
      <value>138 mm</value>
      <label>Overall width w/lever</label>
      <value>35 mm</value>
      <label>Barrel length</label>
      <value>98 mm</value>
      <label>Sight radius</label>
      <value>149 mm</value>
   </Dimensions>
   <Weight>
      <label>With magazine</label>
      <value>739 g</value>
      <label>Magazine</label>
      <value>91 g</value>
   </Weight>
</product>
```

Of course, a better structure would group label and value together under a common parent element.

---

### Edit:

To do the above, replace:

```
<label><xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[8]/fmp:DATA[$i]"/></label>
<value><xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[9]/fmp:DATA[$i]"/></value>
```

with:

```
<value label="{../../fmp:COL[8]/fmp:DATA[$i]}">
     <xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[9]/fmp:DATA[$i]"/>
</value>
```

Comment: What's the best way to get a label in as Buck suggested? Something like this? <value label=xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[8]/fmp:DATA[$i]">
<xsl:value-of select="../../fmp:COL[9]/fmp:DATA[$i]"/>
</value>

Comment: @MikeMuller I thought *I* suggested that... Anyway, see the edit to my post.